# Retrieving a woocommerce parent order on purchase?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-bookings

hoping someone can help with this. It seems like a simple problem but wondering if there's a cleaner way to do it.

Right now I have a hook that runs whenever a WooCommerce order is completed and when a order is updated. That hook is the following:

```
add_action('save_post_shop_order', 'printout', 10, 3);

function printout($post_ID, $post, $update)
{

    $posttype = get_post_type($post_id);
    write_to_log('Post Type:' . $posttype);

    if (!is_admin()){
        return;
    }

    if($update && get_post_type($post_id) === "shop_order"){
        $msg = $post_ID;
        $order = get_woocommerce_order($msg);
        mainplugin($msg, $order);
    }

}


add_action('woocommerce_thankyou', 'neworder_created', 10, 2);


function neworder_created($order_id){
    $order = get_woocommerce_order($order_id);

    mainplugin($order_id, $order);
}
```

The hook to run the plugin on order update works perfect. You'll notice that I have some validation logic in there:

```
if($update && get_post_type($post_id) === "shop_order"){
        $msg = $post_ID;
        $order = get_woocommerce_order($msg);
        mainplugin($msg, $order);
    }
```

This is essentially the functionality I'm trying to replicate for new orders. What happens is when folks make a purchase on my site, 4 database calls are made with the following post types in order of creation:

- wc_booking (child)
- shop_order (parent)
- wcdp_payment (child)
- wcdp_payment (child)

What's happening is the hook for a new order

```
add_action('woocommerce_thankyou', 'neworder_created', 10, 2);
```

is running on the last database call  of a wcdp_payment *instead* of what I need it to; **it should run only on that shop_order DB entry (or I guess the parent order is what I need)**. wcdp_payment is missing order information.

Is there a way to get it to run when a post type is ONLY shop_order? I know I could wire up some logic similar to how I have it set up to handle updates but my concern is that I don't know exactly what this hook is doing, so will it even reach the desired "shop_order" db entry? Or is there a different hook I should be using?

Thank you for your help! Hope this made sense.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what you mean by these 4 db calls

- wc_booking (child)
- shop_order (parent)
- wcdp_payment (child)
- wcdp_payment (child)

buy If you mean you want the function `neworder_created` to be called after the order is created and saved in DB, you can use this hook `woocommerce_checkout_order_created` instead of `woocommerce_thankyou` hook.

It should be like that.

```
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_order_created', 'neworder_created', 10, 1);
```

That hook already passes the order object, so you need to change the function to.

```
function neworder_created($order){
    $order_id = $order->get_id();
    mainplugin($order_id, $order);
}
```